# How I can locate the thread ID in "new Gmail"?

Tags: gmail

When I use the old Gmail I use this method:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/1630209116a3af45` and thread ID is: `1630209116a3af45`.

In the new Gmail, the same thread link is:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?zx=3xcdey2cogvc#inbox/FMfcgxmZVPbZvwJWCvBMvjxglSMPvsvW
```

and there is no option to find it.

I also looked in the HTML source of the page and the thread ID is not there.

All of my searches show only the old Gmail behavior (like this: https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-get-thread-id-of-a-gmail-thread/).

I want to find out how I can locate the thread id.

(I also tried to find it in the "show original" option, but I can find only the message id, and it does not help.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the thread id from the HTML. Try searching "data-legacy-thread-id" in the HTML elements.

Or you can find it by running JavaScript code in the console:

```
document.querySelector('[data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id')
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the answers above do not work every time because the DOM, in some cases, might have more messages and thus many `data-legacy-thread-id`, as can be seen below:
[image: image showing multiple matches for DOM search]

By tweaking the CSS selector a bit you get the correct `data-legacy-thread-id`:

```
document.querySelector('[role="main"] [data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id')
```

To make my life easier I created a bookmarklet using:

```
javascript:(function(){prompt("Legacy Thread ID",document.querySelector('[role="main"] [data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id'))}());
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the missing step to get the right id.  It'd be nice to have one combined answer.

Answer (score 1):

## method 1:

- press **<kbd>F12</kbd>** while email is opened
- go to **Elements**

[image]

## method 2:

- press **<kbd>F12</kbd>** while email is opened
- go to **Console**
- paste: **`document.querySelector('[data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id')`**
- or paste: **`document.querySelector('[role="main"] [data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id')`**
- hit **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: Weird these answers were downvoted, especially without comments.  It helped me realize I could search for the number in the DevTool Elements HTML view easy enough without needing to execute any JavaScript.  The email I wanted was apparently on the first page in my Inbox, so that was easy enough.

Comment: This answer gets the first thread id on the page, which isn't always the thread id being displayed.  See the other answer that addresses that and upvote.